# mysql foreach fwrite

Tags: php, foreach, fwrite

I use some code here, transfer mysql query data into json data and write into a file. where is the problem? why the file is zero kb?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query)){ 
  $arr = array ('name'=>$row['name']);
  $jsondata = json_encode($arr);
  $countfile="data.txt";
  if(!file_exists($countfile))
  {
    fopen($countfile,"w");
  } 
  $fp = fopen($countfile, 'r');
  fwrite($fp, $jsondata);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're reopening the file as read only

`$fp = fopen($countfile, 'r');`

try

`$fp = fopen($countfile, 'w'); // to write`

or

`$fp = fopen($countfile, 'a'); // to append`

you could also open the file for writing at the start, append your rows in a variable and then write it all together to the file.

```
$countfile="data.txt";
$fp = fopen($countfile, 'w');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
{ 
    $arr = array ('name'=>$row['name']);
    $jsondata .= json_encode($arr) . "\n";

}
fwrite($fp, $jsondata);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I am a newer, but use `$fp = fopen($countfile, 'a');` can work well in a foreach situation.

Answer (score 5):

Several things.

- You dont need (and should avoid) to open the file in every iteration
- You open the file read-only (`r`)

At all something like this should do it

```
$countfile="data.txt";
$fp = fopen($countfile, 'w');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
{ 
    $arr = array ('name'=>$row['name']);
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr);

    fwrite($fp, $jsondata);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Additional you append separate json structures into the file, what is probably not, what you want. You should first collect all you want to store into *one* json structure and save it then

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
{ 
    $data[] = array ('name'=>$row['name']);

}
file_put_contents('data.txt', json_encode($data));
```

This feels more like what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file for reading only

```
$fp = fopen($countfile, 'r');
```

You also dont need

```
  if(!file_exists($countfile))
  {
    fopen($countfile,"w");
  }
```

just use:

```
$fp = fopen($countfile, 'w');
```

Comment: `$fp = fopen($countfile, 'w');` just insert the latest one in a foreach in my test. it will delete the eariler data.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file read-only. You probably want `'w'` or `'r+'`.