# php json decode a txt file

Tags: php, json

I have the following file:

**data.txt**

```
{name:yekky}{name:mussie}{name:jessecasicas}
```

I am quite new at PHP. Do you know how I can use the decode the above JSON using PHP?

**My PHP code**

```
var_dump(json_decode('data.txt', true));// var_dump value null

foreach ($data->name as $result) {
        echo $result.'<br />';
    }
```

Comment: I've supplied an answer, but you really just need to look up the PHP manual and see what arguments the functions take, and check out the examples. Also, it should be prior knowledge that if a function operates on a string of data that you first have to load it in via some file I/O function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a string as an argument. Read in the file with `file_get_contents`

```
$json_data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
json_decode($json_data, true);
```

You do need to adjust your sample string to be valid JSON by adding quotes around strings, commas between objects and placing the objects inside a containing array (or object).

```
[{"name":"yekky"}, {"name":"mussie"}, {"name":"jessecasicas"}]
```

Comment: Will fail with the given file

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312535/mysql-foreach-fwrite) you are not producing valid JSON. See my answer there, on how to create it. That will lead to something like

```
[{"name":"yekky"},{"name":"mussie"},{"name":"jessecasicas"}]
```

(I dont know, where your quotes are gone, but `json_encode()` usually produce valid json)

And this is easy readable

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.txt'), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data is invalid. You have multiple objects there (and you're missing quotes), you need some way to separate them before you feed the to `json_decode`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.txt'), true);
```

But your JSON needs to be formatted correctly:

```
[ {"name":"yekky"}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid JSON file, according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).  If it were, you'd have to read it first:

```
$jsonBytes = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonBytes, true);
/* Do something with data.
If you set the second argument of json_decode (as above), it's an array,
otherwise an object.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the file!

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.txt');
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```